# How to do LEFT JOIN in MongoDB aggregate function?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use the aggregate function for getting a particular value from the referenced `collection`. But it's only selecting the records when the main collection is having the field that's used for reference acting like JOIN in RDBMS as like follows,

`movies` collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd9624c57fda41d20f925a4"),
    "name" : "Game over"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf3808e096bc30017e1ffae"),
    "name" : "Kolaigaran"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf229902b18930dba0488ee"),
    "name" : "Devi 2"
}
```

`events` collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a1c9c568edb055ff850bd"),
    "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd9624c57fda41d20f925a4"),
    "resources" : {
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/e8brnxqxb7e6djvpvnrd.jpg", 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/vgsfwnwhykaqhov5zg2b.jpg"
        ],
        "youtubeLinks" : [ 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocnzgwjXdLw", 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLRHNYQ-Dno"
        ]
    },
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a201b568edb055ff850c0"),
    "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd9624c57fda41d20f925a4"),
    "resources" : {
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/qivg8ft6riul8rpfwygy.jpg"
        ]
    },
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a3a50568edb055ff850c1"),
    "movieId" : ObjectId("5cf3808e096bc30017e1ffae"),
    "resources" : {
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/egefgqzddu0jgj0wyagh.jpg", 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/qlnxslo7zobtm3tiqgor.jpg"
        ]
    },
}
```

Here's the query I'm using,

```
db.getCollection('movies').aggregate([
    {
       $lookup:
         {
            from: "events",
            let: { movieId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [ 
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$movieId", "$$movieId"] } } },
                { $project: { resources: { $objectToArray: "$resources" } } },
                { $unwind: "$resources" },
                { $unwind: "$resources.v" },
                { $group: { _id:"$resources.k", "v": { $addToSet:"$resources.v" } } },
                { $group: { _id:null, resources: { $push: { k:"$_id", v:"$v" } } } },
                { $project: { resources: { $arrayToObject: "$resources" } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot:"$resources" } }
            ],
            as: "resources"
         }
    },
    { $unwind: "$resources" }
]);
```

This returns all the documents in the `movies` collection where it has a relation in the `events` collection as follows,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd9624c57fda41d20f925a4"),
    "name" : "Game over",
    "resources" : {
        "youtubeLinks" : [ 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLRHNYQ-Dno", 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocnzgwjXdLw"
        ],
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/qivg8ft6riul8rpfwygy.jpg", 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/vgsfwnwhykaqhov5zg2b.jpg", 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/e8brnxqxb7e6djvpvnrd.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf3808e096bc30017e1ffae"),
    "name" : "Kolaigaran",
    "resources" : {
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/qlnxslo7zobtm3tiqgor.jpg", 
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/run-up/posters/egefgqzddu0jgj0wyagh.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't have the third document in the movies as it doesn't have any relation in the events collection.

Here is what I've tried by modifying `$match` part in the query like follows but not working,

```
{ $match: { $or: [ { $expr: { $eq: ["$movieId", "$$movieId"] } }, { resources: { $exists: false } } ] } }
```

I'm not sure if `$match` is the exact part that should be changed to include the other results.

Any help on this would be greatly useful and much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you could use the regular way of joining `{ $lookup: { from: '', foreignField: '', localField: '', as: '$data' } }`
then you can make the `$project` to `$data` like you make in let this will en light things

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks, I got it